# Challenging Integration, cannot get anywhere with by parts or by sub.

Tags: integration

Doing some math for a project of mine where I have used this equation for a line of best fit:

$$ (1-(1-x)^a)^{\frac{1}{a}} $$

I need to find the area underneath this curve, between $0$ and $1$, for all real values of a between $0$ and $1$.

Does anyone know how to do this efficiently or elegantly?

Comment: The answer is the non-elementary expression $(1+\frac2a)B(1+\frac1a,1+\frac1a)$, where $B(x,y)$ is the [Euler Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). So except for special values of $a$ such as $\frac12$, there won't be a simpler expression.

Comment: @GregMartin Can you please elaborate? Never heard of the Euler Beta function before.

Comment: Major improvements have been achieved. Have a look at what I added. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from @Greg Martin's solution
$$I(a)=\left(1+\frac2a\right)B(1+\frac1a,1+\frac1a)$$ you can  also write it as
$$I(a)=\sqrt{\pi }\left(1+\frac2a\right) 2^{-\frac{a+2}{a}}\frac{ \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{a}\right)}$$ which, may be, is more familiar to you.

Now, we can make *approximations*.

Close to $a=0$, we have
$$I(a)=\sqrt{\pi a}\left(1+\frac2a\right) 2^{-\frac{a+2}{a}}\Big[1+\sum_{k=1}^n c_k\, a^k \Big]$$ where the $c_k$'s make the sequence
$$\left\{-\frac{3}{8},\frac{25}{128},-\frac{105}{1024},\frac{1659}{32768},-\frac{6237
   }{262144},\frac{50765}{4194304},-\frac{242385}{33554432}\right\}$$

Trying for a few values of $a$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.15 & 0.000452 & 0.000452 \\
 0.20 & 0.003968 & 0.003968 \\
 0.25 & 0.014286 & 0.014286 \\
 0.30 & 0.033065 & 0.033065 \\
 0.35 & 0.059604 & 0.059604 \\
 0.40 & 0.092039 & 0.092039 \\
 0.45 & 0.128318 & 0.128319 \\
 0.50 & 0.166664 & 0.166667 \\
 0.55 & 0.205700 & 0.205707 \\
 0.60 & 0.244436 & 0.244451 \\
 0.65 & 0.282193 & 0.282227 \\
 0.70 & 0.318535 & 0.318605 \\
 0.75 & 0.353194 & 0.353328 \\
 0.80 & 0.386022 & 0.386266 \\
 0.85 & 0.416948 & 0.417373 \\
 0.90 & 0.445946 & 0.446661 \\
 0.95 & 0.473017 & 0.474179 \\
 1.00 & 0.498163 & 0.500000
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

We can improve the approximation for "large" values of $a$, writing
$$\frac{ \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{a}\right)}=\frac{4}{3 \sqrt{\pi }}+\sum_{k=1}^n d_k\, (a-1)^k $$
$$d_1=\frac{4 (5-6 \log (2))}{9 \sqrt{\pi }} \qquad d_2=\frac{52-6 \pi ^2+12 \log (2) (6 \log (2)-4)}{27 \sqrt{\pi }}$$

**Update**

We can have a significant improvement writing
$$I(a)=\sqrt{\pi a}\left(1+\frac2a\right) 2^{-\frac{a+2}{a}}\color{red}{\frac{ \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\sqrt a \,\Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{a}\right)}}$$ and build for the "red" term its $[4,4]$ Padé approximant.

This will write
$$\frac{ \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\sqrt a \,\Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{a}\right)}=
\frac {1+\sum_{k=1}^4 \frac {b_k } {c_k }a^k } {1+\sum_{k=1}^4 \frac {d_k } {c_k }a^k }$$ The coefficients $(b_k,c_k,d_k)$ are given below

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 k & b_k & c_k & d_k \\
 1 & -45050201133 & 24342404336 & -35921799507 \\
 2 & -157157838285 & 389478469376 & -448758648877 \\
 3 & -3283793920545 & 3115827755008 & -3412530822591 \\
 4 & -13005546423289 & 99706488160256 & -51653145742649
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comparison
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.15 & 0.000452 & 0.000452 \\
 0.20 & 0.003968 & 0.003968 \\
 0.25 & 0.014286 & 0.014286 \\
 0.30 & 0.033065 & 0.033065 \\
 0.35 & 0.059604 & 0.059604 \\
 0.40 & 0.092039 & 0.092039 \\
 0.45 & 0.128326 & 0.128319 \\
 0.50 & 0.166669 & 0.166667 \\
 0.55 & 0.205709 & 0.205707 \\
 0.60 & 0.244455 & 0.244451 \\
 0.65 & 0.282234 & 0.282227 \\
 0.70 & 0.318614 & 0.318605 \\
 0.75 & 0.353342 & 0.353328 \\
 0.80 & 0.386286 & 0.386266 \\
 0.85 & 0.417402 & 0.417373 \\
 0.90 & 0.446702 & 0.446661 \\
 0.95 & 0.474235 & 0.474179 \\
 1.00 & 0.500075 & 0.500000
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is much better that before.

Notice, that the difference between this Padé approximant and the Taylor series of the red term is about $\frac{a^9}{447}$.

Encouraged by this improvement, a nonlinear regression was made based on $1001$ equally spaced data points (there is a constraint on coefficient $c_4$ to match the end point). Making the coefficients rational, the result is
$$\frac{ \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\sqrt a \,\Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{a}\right)}=
\frac{1+\frac{6616 }{4209}a+\frac{2610 }{2143}a^2+\frac{343 }{1313}a^3+\frac{5}{793}a^4 } {1+\frac{4727 }{2428}a+\frac{3104 }{1771}a^2+\frac{619 }{966}a^3+\frac{173}{3250}a^4 }$$ and, as shown below the fit is extremely good with very highly significant coefficients.

$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 b_1 & 1.5718699 & 0.00091 & \{1.57008,1.57366\} \\
 b_2 & 1.2179188 & 0.00088 & \{1.21620,1.21964\} \\
 b_3 & 0.2612339 & 0.00026 & \{0.26073,0.26174\} \\
 b_4 & 0.0063051 & 0.00001 & \{0.00628,0.00633\} \\
 c_1 & 1.9468699 & 0.00091 & \{1.94508,1.94866\} \\
 c_2 & 1.7526822 & 0.00122 & \{1.75029,1.75507\} \\
 c_3 & 0.6407868 & 0.00054 & \{0.63973,0.64184\} \\
\end{array}$$

Using the above, the maximum absolute error on $I(a)$ is smaller than $\color{red}{4\times 10^{-9}}$.